# Libgdx Scene2d Table and Scrollpane bug?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I tried to do a simple scrollable table with buttons. Here is the code:

```
craft = new Stage();
craftbl = new Table();
craftbl.setDebug(true);
craftbl.add(button1);
craftbl.row();
craftbl.add(button2);
scroll = new ScrollPane(craftbl);
scroll.setSize(640, 480);
craft.addActor(scroll);
```

But as a result I have only one button on screen:[image: ?]

How can i fix it?

Comment: Please show us how you create the buttons, because its working in my side. Thank you

Comment: [Code is here](http://pastebin.com/T6H61D2P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. To fix this, you need to set size at least of one of table's cells. E.G. like this: `table.add(somewidget).width(100);`